# Polar plots ticks in degrees -180 to 180

Tags: plotting

I am trying to create a polar plot with the ticks in degrees, but instead of 0 to 360, I want -180 to 180. `PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}` gives 0 - 360, but I don't' see how to get 0 to 180 on the top and 0 to -180 on the bottom.

Comment: Have you seen [How to change the radius markers and number of concentric circles in a polar plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79363/how-to-change-the-radius-markers-and-number-of-concentric-circles-in-a-polar-plo)

Answer (score 2):

```
PolarPlot[n^2, {n, 0, 10},
 PolarAxes -> {True, False},
 PolarTicks ->
  {Transpose[{
     Range[0, 23] Pi/12,
     Join[#, -Reverse[#][[2 ;; -2]]] &[Range[0, 180, 15]] Degree}], 
   Automatic},
 Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help.